# How to debug NullPointerException on getOntClass()?

Tags: nullpointerexception, jena

I'm working with `Jena` and I'm trying to create a Class in my ontology during  runtime.
This is my function to create the class :

`static public boolean createClass(Model model, String className){
    String namespace = "http://www.myontologyexemple.com#";
    OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM, model);
    OntClass myClass = ontModel.createClass(namespace + className);
    OntClass mother = ontModel.getOntClass(namespace + "mother");// returns null
    m2m.addSubClass(myClass);
    return(myClass.getSuperClass().equals(mother));
  }`

As Commented on my code I get a null when trying to get the "mother" class. I tested and the class exists under the namespace.
Also, not that it may be the source of the problem, but this code is part of a bundle on `Karaf`.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Turns out I was using the wrong Spec for my model that's why it couldn't create the class. Instead of `OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM` I used  `OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF` which I should have seen sooner and not after 3 days of trying to solve the problem.